# HTML doesn't show up in post body

Tags: support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I was answering [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353248/how-to-specify-add-shortcut-to-home-screen-icon-on-android-for-a-web-application), and needed to include HTML in my answer, but it didn't show up. For example:

I worked around it by adding a space before the tag name:

< html>

but that's an ugly workaround. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure what your asking, but try selecting the HTML and clicking the `{}` button on the editor toolbar. That should indent the HTML by four spaces (the markdown way to format code blocks).

Comment: That's because the code block is in a list, you have to indent 4 spaces more than usual.

Comment: It appears that someone has edited your answer so that the HTML renders as code. I'd suggest you look at how they've formatted your answer.

Comment: Thinking better, it is not exactly a duplicate, as the other question doesn't say anything about the 8 spaces required in a list.

Comment: This is not the first time. You have [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8613309/229044) which are broken because you're using HTML tags without escaping them. You've posted 70 answers, it might be finally time to [learn to use the editor](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Please stop using "&" instead of "and" while you're at it.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to indent the code of 4 spaces, outside a list, and 8 spaces in a list. Differently, HTML tags that are not allowed are filtered out; the other HTML tags are rendered.

```
<html>
```

- Inside a list

  ```
  <html>
  ```
- Second dot

  ```
  <html>
  ```

Without indenting it, you get the following:

You can *not* use Markdown in here. `<em>` is rendered
 `<html>` is filtered out

What I wrote in the previous lines in the following:

```
You can <em>not</em> use Markdown in here. `<em>` is rendered  
<html> `<html>` is filtered out
```